# Creating objects from interface in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm new to javascript and typescript. I am trying to declare variable from interface. I want to fill the value of initialized variable at later point. Then I would like to push all such variables to an array of interface type.

Is this the right way to do this?

```
interface Car{
    name: string;
    year?: number;
}

let c1: Car = {} as Car;
c1.name = "Audi";

let c2: Car = {} as Car;
c2.name = "BMW";

let c: Array<Car> = [];
c.push(c1);
c.push(c2);
```

Comment: You declare `c1` as an object of type `Car` and then you don't care about that and initialize it with `{}` (incorrectly asserted to be a `Car`). It doesn't make any sense. Use `let c1: Car = { name: 'Audi' };` instead. And `let c: Array<Car> = [ c1, c2 ];`

Comment: @axiac - Admittedly the code above could be condensed to what you recommend in your comments. That said I do not see anything "wrong" with it. It is functionally equivalent to your code.

Comment: `Is this the right way to do this?` <= You could shorten it up by in-lining the value assignments both for the array and the fields/properties. Other than that suggestion your code is OK.

Comment: Also it is not clear (to me) if you also had a question about `let` or that was just extraneous information in the title of your question.

Comment: @Igor It seems to me OP is under the impression that the `let` was relevant because they are mutating `c1`/`c2` (as opposed to `const`). And in fact it *would* be relevant if they later assigned a `c1 = { name: "Audi" }`, but not as it's written currently. This is a fairly common misunderstanding about mutability and `const` vs `let`.

Comment: I am getting the values as string in json object. I am splitting the string and and structuring with interface. Finally I am trying to push all objects of that interface into an array.

Answer (score 0):

You declare `c1` as an object of type `Car` and then you don't care about that and initialize it with `{}` (incorrectly asserted to be a `Car`). It doesn't make any sense.

Use `let c1: Car = { name: 'Audi' };` instead.
And `let c: Array<Car> = [ c1, c2 ];` to declare and initialize the array.

```
interface Car {
    name: string;
    year?: number;
}

let c1: Car = { name: 'Audi' };
let c2: Car = { name: 'BMW', year: 2015 };

let c: Array<Car> = [c1, c2];
```

Shorter, cleaner, OOP-like.

Comment: I know `c1` is of car type, but I don't have the values to initialize it. They are provided to me at later point. I was revisiting this question about why I didn't accept the answer .. thought this would be useful